# DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (dbname) runs successfully but does not fix the "disk usage report"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I ran the DBCC UPDATEUSAGE command on our Dev box to see if it fixes the 'disk usage report'. It ran quickly ( 10 seconds) and ran successfully but did not fix the report. Any ideas about what the issue could be?
Thanks!

[image: Disk Usage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These numbers on the disk usage report look correct. It's important to note that the Total Space Reserved is displayed in GB, using the conversion `1024 MB = 1 GB`

The formula used by the above report is straightforward:

**Data File Space Reserved + Transaction Log Space Reserved = Total Disk Space Reserved**

```
279,860.56 MB + 90.63 MB = 279,951.19 MB

279,951.19 MB / 1024 = 273.39 GB
```

Comment: Indeed you are correct sir! I should have caught that. Thanks!